# Simplifying query by adding Computed Column, performance impact?

Tags: performance, t-sql, sql-server-2000, query-performance

The dev team came across the following query (might be incomplete; it's retyped from a screenshot) which had caused slowness:

```
SELECT d.catalogno, d.itemid,
  SUM(lineamount+taxamount) AS Amount,
  SUM(qty) AS Qty,
  CASE
    WHEN d.costprice>=d.basiccostprice THEN d.costprice
    WHEN d.costprice<d.basiccostprice THEN d.basiccostprice
  END AS cog,
  d.salesprice,
  CASE
    WHEN d.costprice>=d.basiccostprice THEN d.salesprice/d.costprice
    WHEN d.costprice<d.basiccostprice THEN d.salesprice/d.basiccostprice
  END AS coeff
FROM custinvoicetrans t
WITH (nolock)
INNER JOIN
  pwlmy_dcatalog d
  WITH (nolock)
  ON t.itemid=d.itemid
INNER JOIN
  pwlmy_hcatalog h
  WITH (nolock)
  ON h.catalogno=d.catalogno
WHERE
  t.invoicedate>=h.effectivedatefrom
GROUP BY
  d.catalogno, d.itemid,
  CASE
    WHEN d.costprice>=d.basiccostprice THEN d.costprice
    WHEN d.costprice<d.basiccostprice THEN d.basiccostprice
  END,
  d.salesprice,
  CASE
    WHEN d.costprice>=d.basiccostprice THEN d.salesprice/d.costprice
    WHEN d.costprice<d.basiccostprice THEN d.salesprice/d.basiccostprice
  END
```

I'm wondering... if I create a view like such:

```
CREATE VIEW pwlmy_dcatalog_cog AS
  SELECT *,
    CASE
      WHEN costprice>=basiccostprice THEN costprice
      WHEN costprice<basiccostprice THEN basiccostprice
    END AS cog
  FROM pwlmy_dcatalog
```

I should be able to simplify the query to the following:

```
SELECT d.catalogno, d.itemid,
  SUM(lineamount+taxamount) AS Amount,
  SUM(qty) AS Qty,
  d.cog,
  d.salesprice,
  d.salesprice/d.cog AS coeff,
FROM custinvoicetrans t
WITH (nolock)
INNER JOIN
  pwlmy_dcatalog_cog d
  WITH (nolock)
  ON t.itemid=d.itemid
INNER JOIN
  pwlmy_hcatalog h
  WITH (nolock)
  ON h.catalogno=d.catalogno
WHERE
  t.invoicedate>=h.effectivedatefrom
GROUP BY
  d.catalogno, d.itemid,
  d.cog,
  d.salesprice,
  d.salesprice/d.cog
```

Do you think the simplified query will have a significant impact to overall performance?

***Note:*** I don't dare add a computed column into the `pwlmy_dcatalog` table; codes relying on that table might break spectacularly.

Comment: Why would adding a computed column break something else?

Comment: @MarkSinkinson suppose there's a code, somewhere, doing `SELECT * FROM pwlmy_dcatalog WHERE <some criteria>`, and the code relies on the exact number of columns...

Comment: Well, you need to fix your code. You can't be afraid to fix your database in case it breaks some sloppy code somewhere that violates best practices in a number of ways...

Comment: @AaronBertrand problem is, it's not _my_ code... I'm just receiving notification that this query is causing some slowness... :(

Comment: You need to determine why it's slow, and not jump to the conclusion that it must be because of these calculations (or that putting them into a view will fix it). Have you investigated a query plan, to see where SQL Server is spending its time and doing work?

Answer (score 3):

Moving the calculation to the view won't change performance - it's still done at runtime. So all you've changed is the complexity of the outer query.

In order to change performance you would need to add the computed column to the table, and persist it or [index it](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933138(v=sql.80).aspx). This means the work of the calculation is done at insert/update time instead of query time. (Persisting only works in 2005+.)

Now, other factors are at play too. For example, do you have any evidence that this calculation actually affects performance? Maybe the query performs the same without it? Also using the view may cause other performance issues, for example if it involves additional columns, calculations or tables that this query doesn't actually need.

Comment: Persisted computed columns are SQL Server 2005 onwards though, so perhaps not the appropriate solution here?

Comment: @Mark whoops, didn't even see the 2000 tag.